# How to set form name in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I create my custom form in this way:

```
$messageForm = $this->createFormBuilder( new MessageEmailForm() )
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->getForm();
```

I would like to change form name but I don't know how to do it and simultaneously **hold MessageEmailForm class in FormBuilder**. I tried something like that:

```
 $this->createFormBuilder( new MessageEmailForm(), "myCustomFormName" )
```

etc. but it doesn't work. I need exactly this result:

```
<form name="myCustomFormName" ... >
```

@EDIT//
I found information about my problem, it looks like I should use following code but I have no idea where I should use it...

```
$this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to generate this:

```
<form name="myCustomFormName" ... >
```

Just add this in the twig template:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': { 'name':'myCustomFormName' }})  }}
```

Comment: This solution is by the book ;)

Comment: I can't do that becouse I have 2 forms on 1 page and even if I set a name in <form>, it won't work for inputs below, becouse they will get name "form[name]", not "myCustomFormName[name]".

Comment: Please check at this answer work propertly for me ! https://stackoverflow.com/a/37009914/4526175

Answer (score 0):

Could you add the attribute to your twig template.

```
{# src/Acme/TaskBundle/Resources/views/Default/new.html.twig #}
<form action="{{ path('task_new') }}" name="myCustomFormName" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```