# Symfony3: is it possible to change the name of a form?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

With **Symfony 2.7**, you could customize a form's name in your EntityType class with the method `getName()`
This is now deprecated. Is there another way to do that with **Symfony 3.0** ?
I have custom prototype entry_rows for collections that I would need to use in different forms.
Since the name of the rows is based on the form's name, I would need to change the later in order to use them with a different form.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to rely on a custom form name. Why can't you change your collections? I'm using collections a lot, but I didn't face this problem.

Comment: @StephanVierkant Why is it a bad idea? If you know of some problem it might lead to, please tell me, as I'm gonna use Matteo's answer. I don't want to change my collections because I have two forms: formA with field myCollection, and formB, which also has a field myCollection. So in my prototype custom form, if I write a block like _formA_myCollection_entry_row, it won't be recognized when I call my formB, because this time it will be called _formB_myCollection_entry_row. Hope I'm clear...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You should implements the `getBlockPrefix` method instead of `getName` as described in the migration guide [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.3/UPGRADE-3.0.md#form).

As example:

```
/**
 * Returns the prefix of the template block name for this type.
 *
 * The block prefix defaults to the underscored short class name with
 * the "Type" suffix removed (e.g. "UserProfileType" => "user_profile").
 *
 * @return string The prefix of the template block name
 */
public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return "form_name";
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: This is just what I needed! You solved my problem! I didn't know the form name was now called blockPrefix, that's what I didn't find it in the official doc. Thanks for the migration guide link, I'll try to have a look at it next time I'm looking for a pre-3.0 functionality.

Comment: Official Doc: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-the-form-type-template

Answer (score 34):

Depending on how your form is built, there is different ways to set the name of your form.

If you are creating the form through `$this->createForm(CustomType::class)`:

```
$formFactory = $this->get('form.factory');
$form = $formFactory->createNamed('custom_form_name', CustomType::class);
```

If you are building the form from the controller directly through `$this->createFormBuilder()`:

```
$formFactory = $this->get('form.factory');
$form = $formFactory->createNamedBuilder('custom_form_name', CustomType::class);
```

Look at the [FormFactory](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.html) and [FormBuilder](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.html) APIs for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I chose Matteo's because it's more appropriate for my particular needs, but I'm sure yours will be helpfull for someone else.

Comment: @Roubi And you're totally right, it fits your issue exactly

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was re-using the same sorta generic form three times on a page and needed a way to have unique ids for the fields.  This method worked perfectly for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it, remove prefix on field name

```
public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return null;
}
```