# Symfony3 - Form getName();

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a problem with form and getting parameters from url, when using GET method.
In Symfony2 I could use this in form type:

```
public function getName()
{
    return null;
}
```

and it returned me just field name without formname[**fieldname**].
But now I have Symfony 3, and this function doesn't work for me.

So it's possible to return just fieldname?
Because my url now looks like this:

> [www.example.com/search?search%5Bkeyword%5D=zzz](http://www.example.com/search?search%5Bkeyword%5D=zzz)

And this: `$request->query->get('keyword');` returns null.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37005899/symfony3-is-it-possible-to-change-the-name-of-a-form/37011487#37011487) approach also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `createNamed()`:

```
// 1st arg: form name; 2nd arg: form type
$formFactory->createNamed(null, YourType::class);
```